# Refactoring .catch(handleError) throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to refactor my catch block since it is common for multiple request. But it throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: next is not defined.

Here is a code snippet.

```
user.save()
    .then(user => {

    })
    .catch(handleError)

const handleError = err => {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err)
}
```

However if I do it this way it works

```
user.save()
    .then(user => {

    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (!err.statusCode) {
            err.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(err)
    })
```

Comment: where is `next` defined?

Comment: next is a default function inside a middleware but here it is some reference error.

Comment: I think you're mistaken regarding `next` being a default function. When it seems to work, I bet that's something from an outer scope which hasn't been shown (likely, express middleware). Typically, `next` is given as a parameter to the handler callback function.

Answer (score 2):

`const` is not hoisted, so you need to move it above the use location:

```js
const errHandler = console.log("Hello world");
new Promise((res, reject) => reject()).then(errHandler);
```

rather than:

```js
new Promise((res, reject) => reject()).then(errHandler);
const errHandler = console.log("Hello world");
```

Comment: I have edited my question. It says next is not defined so I cannot call the next middleware.

Comment: I see. It's always good to post the error you're getting up front. I don't see that either snippet works since `next` isn't present in either one. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Any solutions?

Comment: Without a [mcve], it's hard to say, but I don't see a parameter for `next`. Try adding it and putting the `const` above the use point.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
user.save().then(user => {})
    .catch(err => handleError(err))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put your handler above, like this

```
const handleError = err => {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err)
}

user.save()
    .then(user => {

    })
    .catch(handleError)
```

or you can rewrite the handler like this

```
function handleError(err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err)
}
```